# Playing the same music file in the same time on speaker and earpiece, Android

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to do it on android? Ofc I'm talking about phones that use only one speaker for media playback. My phone is Nexus5X. I dont want to root it or mess with system files cause of warranty. So can an app without root be made to do smth like that?

p.s. I tried SoundAbout didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to play a music file in phone speaker as well as Head Phone. If Yes means,  It's Possible.

```
// Read the music file from the asset folder
            afd = this.getAssets().openFd("background_music.mp3");
// Creation of new media player;
            player = new MediaPlayer();
// Set the player music source.
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
               player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
// Set the looping and play the music.
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
```

Here `player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);` will act as alarm service, means the audio in the asset folder will play in both headphones and speaker.

Hope it will Help you....